# Does dconf default terminal profile UUID change between Ubuntu installations?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, settings, system-settings, dconf

I would like to make my dconf setting portable, thus I'm writing it out to a file with `dconf dump / > file`. However, when it comes of terminal profile setting, my profile UUID is included

```
[org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9]
visible-name='artu-hnrq'
use-theme-colors=false
1use-transparent-background=true
background-transparency-percent=8
```

So, supposing each Ubuntu installation generates a different default terminal profile UUID, I'm considering the dump file won't apply the desired configuration properly, since the target installation terminal profile UUID won't be the same when I run `dconf load / < file` in another computer.

This way I would like to read the machine terminal profile UUID before set up dconf keys.

Is there a way to work with variables inside this file?
Or is there another way to working around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly, the default (first) profile has this ID on every computer.

The list of gnome-terminal profiles, as well the default one, are stored in `org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list` and `org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/default`, respectively. You can query and restore them with `dconf` just as you do with the profiles themselves (e.g. `dconf read [...]`), or use their result in constructing the next `dconf` command line.